# Sender SignatureDoesNotMatch Signature expired

Tags: php, amazon-ses

Hi my code running perfect few day ago, I check today there give me error while sending email using amazon ses service

Error executing "SendEmail" on "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: Sender SignatureDo (truncated...) SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): Signature expired: 20160718T125547Z is now earlier than 20160718T125616Z (20160718T130116Z - 5 min.) - Sender SignatureDoesNotMatch Signature expired: 20160718T125547Z is now earlier than 20160718T125616Z (20160718T130116Z - 5 min.) b64acacc-4ce7-11e6-adb5-0992ceb0921c

my code is:

```
require_once("aws/aws-autoloader.php");
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

define('SENDER', 'no-reply@example.net');

    define('RECIPIENT', 'my@example.com');    
    define('REGION','us-west-2');

    $client = SesClient::factory(array(
        'version'=> 'latest',     
        'region' => REGION,
        'credentials' => array(
            'key'    => '******************',
            'secret' => '*****************************',
        )
    ));

    $request = array();
    $request['Source'] = SENDER;
    $request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array(RECIPIENT);
    $request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = $subject;
    $request['Message']['Body']['Text']['Data'] = $message;

    try {
         $result = $client->sendEmail($request);
         $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo($e->getMessage()."\n");

    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your server's clock?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot my server time is different from amazon server time

Comment: That would be the problem.

Comment: which time zone used by amazon server? i will set that time zone  on our server as default timezone and how correctClockSkew used write any example @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Like most servers, Amazon servers use UTC, but it is probably not your time *zone* that is the problem.  Any good library handles the necessary conversions correctly.  Your clock simply needs to be set to the correct, current time in the time zone to which it is set, whatever that is.  Expired and skewed are typically (though not necessarily) two symptoms of the same problem.  Ubuntu? `sudo apt-get install ntp`. Amazon Linux? `sudo yum install ntp`.

Comment: I got a similar error when working with terraform: `error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: SignatureDoesNotMatch: Signature expired`. Adjusting/fixing the date/time of my virtual machine was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From [Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437748/sender-signaturedoesnotmatch-signature-expired/72916260#comment64320293_38437748):

> Like most servers, Amazon servers use UTC, but it is probably not your time zone that is the problem. Any good library handles the necessary conversions correctly. Your clock simply needs to be set to the correct, current time in the time zone to which it is set, whatever that is. Expired and skewed are typically (though not necessarily) two symptoms of the same problem. Ubuntu? `sudo apt-get install ntp`. Amazon Linux? `sudo yum install ntp`.

i.e.

- Sync your local clock using ntp
- Search how to use it in your OS